# #VALUE! issue because of another formula in corresponding cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I cannot seem to overcome this issue showing `#VALUE!`, please see images.

```
=(I16/D$3)+(J16/D$2)

=IF(F16<>"",MAX(150,(F16+G16)*2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Your Question is extremely unclear. Please [look at this article on asking a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dividing by a cell value that might be null, interpreted as zero, is illegal (in most locales).

Comment: formula seems to work fine for me, that is if you want it to return True/False

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this formula is in column K:

```
=(I16/D$3)+(J16/D$2)
```

If both I16 and J16 are blank, it resolves to 0:
[image]

However, if there's any text in those cells, such as a space:
[image]

So, please confirm that I and J are actually empty by selecting them and pressing delete.

You can work around the error by simply changing the formula:

```
=IFERROR((I16/D$3)+(J16/D$2), 0)
```

Assuming this formula is in column M:

```
=IF(F16<>"",MAX(150,(F16+G16)*2),"")
```

Then if F15 is blank, it returns blank:
[image]

However, if F16 is not blank, such as containing a space or some other invisible text:

[image]

Again, you can work around this issue with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(F16<>"",MAX(150,(F16+G16)*2),""),"")
```

I suspect you have some text in column F and possibly in either column I, column J or both.

You can either remove the text or use IFERROR to handle the errors caused by the text.